# Error on generating JAXB Classes from TKT_ElectronicDocumentServices_v.1.0.0.xsd

Tags: sabre

im having trouble generating JAXB classes from TKT_ElectronicDocumentServices_v.1.0.0.xsd and STL_For_TKT_ElectronicDocumentServices_v.1.0.0.xsd, please see error in the image below:

[Please see error here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfEhh.png)

Answer (score 0):

could You share some more info ?

1. What API are You trying to build these WSDLs for ?

My guess is **GetElectronicDocumentRQ**.

2. Is this API available on https://developer.sabre.com/ ?

My guess is

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/air/fulfill/get_electronic_document

3. Have You reached out to webservices.support **at** sabre.com ?

I can see this issue on my end when using dev studio, I've emailed the team, once we have a JIRA open I'll let You know. Also feel free to contact me in this one case at witold.petriczek **at** sabre.com.

P.s. I've ran into these issues while developing SOAP APIs in the past, it was quite often so in my internal team we implemented automated wsdl2java nightly builds that solved this problem once and for all, I guess it's time to share the knowledge with the owners of this API ;)

Regards,
W

Comment: Hi Witold,

Yes im trying to generate this xsd in order to map the response from GetElectronicDocumentRQ,, you are correct i got this from https://developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/air/fulfill/get_electronic_document
I have not reached out yet to  webservices.support@sabre.com

Thanks

Comment: Hello again, we've had someone from Ticketing in Sabre reach out and comment in our internal JIRA:


The Amount in the STL XSD and the Amount in the E-DOC XSD are in different namespaces. 

So, there should be no collision. We generate JAXB POJOs from these same schemas without any issues.

The Amount in the STL XSD is in the namespace: xmlns="http://www.sabre.com/ns/Ticketing/EDocStl"


The Amount in the E-DOC XSD is in the namespace: xmlns="http://www.sabre.com/ns/Ticketing/EDoc"


Are we sure their JAXB invocation is namespace-aware?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/hVZlNav <= Here's the Image.
Have You had the time to contact webservices.support ?